# Does reading mantra/shruti etc. Frees you from all sins as they are mentioned in last of many verses

Tags: karma, belief

Being freed from ***all*** ***sins*** by reading mantras /stutis Or chanting.

Is it **symbolic or literal??**

Verses

'जो सत बार पाठ कर कोई, **छूटहि बंदि** महासुख होई'

Hanuman chalisa

'वासुदेवाश्रयो मत्यों वासुदेवपरायणः । **सर्वपापविशुद्धात्मा** याति ब्रह्म सनातनम् ॥ १३०॥'

Vishnu shastranaam anushasan parva

"Kshantavyo me aparaadhah, Shiva Shiva Shiva bho Shrii Mahaadeva Shambho., 1"

Shiva Aparadha Kshamapana Stotram

*(My opinion : these only forgive minor sins)*

Comment: In ramcharitamanas, it is written that anyone who dies in kashi Or saryu attains moksha? So if a criminal of society dies in kashi Or saryu will he also attain moksha